# pscp command for a range of files

Tags: linux

Can someone help me with writing a pscp mask that will return the following files (up to 9 generations)?  Since I am not doing this at the linux console, I can't use tail.

```
stdout.log
stdout.log.1
stdout.log.2
stdout.log.3
stdout.log.4
stdout.log.5
stdout.log.6
stdout.log.7
stdout.log.8
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about `pscp`, but with reg'ler `scp`, you can use remote globbing (provided you escape it).  e.g. "`scp remote:/tmp/stdout\* /local/dest`"

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to do exactly what you ask (and suspect it may not be possible), but maybe you could do it in 2 passes, eg

pscp stdout.log
pscp stdout.log.[1-8]

Alternatively maybe you could copy the files of interest into a subdirectory and operate on that?